# your app launched to a black screen and no further content loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, appstore-approval

I published my app for the App Store and it got rejected because the app launched with a blank screen and no further content was loaded on the iPad but the app is working fine for me. I try it on the iPad and iPhone and I don't see any problems! what can I do?
Image: [Rejected by apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtbm7.png)

Comment: try to run with `iPad` same iOS version.

Comment: Make sure you test a TestFlight build on a real device. Check that your app works correctly when there is no network connection and on a pure ipv6 network.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try your app on every iPad simulator
2. If possible run it on a real iPad
3. Make sure you are doing all of your UI on the main thread

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController", sender: self);
       });